# How to add data in csv files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, csv

I am unable to add data in an existing csv file. The code gives me no error, but data is not added at the last of file. If I remove the append mode then it truncates the file and then the data is successfully added, but all my previous data inside the file is lost.

So I want to add new records, i.e., append into file and not truncate it.

`csvFile.writeAsString(csvString,mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);`

cvString here is the converted string with the help of `ListToCsvConverter().convert()`

Comment: What you can do is read the existing file into your app in a List, add the new ones to the end of the list and write out the List as a new CSV file.

Comment: I thought of that, but the existing csv file is huge, so it is going to take a lot of time.

Comment: Ok, scratch that idea. I have to look at this in detail but am busy at the moment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.